# Magento2: move footer-container to root

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, footer, page-layouts

I am developing a new Magento 2 theme based on Magento Blank parent.
I am trying to move the footer-container outside the page-wrapper container. To do so I inserted in my `app/design/frontend/custom/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`
the following instruction:

```
<move element="footer" destination="root" after="-" />
```

The footer content is correctly moved outside the **page-wrapper** container but it is not wrapped anymore in the footer tag. What I get is:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">...</div>
<div class="footer content">...</div>
```

What I expected was

```
<div class="page-wrapper">...</div>
<footer class="page-footer">
    <div class="footer content">...</div>
</footer>
```

What should I do to keep the footer tag? Should I redeclare a new container with `htmlTag="footer"` in my `default.xml` and move the footer element inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me it has been redefining a new footer container in the `default.xml` file and move the footer content inside it:

```
<body>
    <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
    <move element="footer" destination="footer-container" before="-"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the container by its name not its alias. The footer element you're looking for is declared in Magento/Theme/view/frontend/page_layout/1column.xml and has a name of footer-container. Changing your layout XML to the following should fix the issue:

```
<move element="footer-container" destination="root" after="-" />
```

Right now what you're doing is moving the child element with the name footer outside of footer-container. Since the footer-container no longer has any children the `<footer>` doesn't get rendered and you only see the child element you moved.

Comment: I tried your solution, but the footer still disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code :

```
<footer class="page-footer">
       <move element="footer" destination="root" after="-" />
</footer>
```

Instead of:

```
 <move element="footer" destination="root" after="-" />
```

Comment: I can't see your code

Comment: You can use this code.

Comment: In this way all the footer content goes away, the div with class "footer content" disappears

Comment: I use it inmy project & its showing after "maincontent" class

Comment: after main content section <footer> section is created inside <div class="page-wrapper">...</div>

Comment: I give another try. The footer is showing after the "maincontent" class but it is still inside the page-wrapper container instead of being on the root. I need to move the footer outside that wrapper.

Comment: <move element="footer"  destination= "modals-wrapper" before="-"/>   use it

Comment: It does not work, the footer tag disappears also in this way

Comment: The only that worked for me was to redefine a new footer container